Repeatability coefficient and Standard error of Measurement
The repeatability coefficient (CR) (Bland Altman) is used to report repeatability understood as the index that compares measurements with the same subject, the same observer and in a short space of time.
The standard error of the measurement is used to report the reliability of an instrument or scale. That is, several measurements of several subjects using one scale or instrument.
Both are absolute measurements supporting their practical usefulness.
But how would the two results be interpreted combined? I am getting a bad result for CR, but good in SEM in terms of reliability.
Maybe I should adjust the SEM to SEM95, since the CR has that adjustment intrinsically?
The experiment is as follows: 10 subjects are measured 4 times consecutively under the same conditions. This is repeated 4 times in 5 different positions.
The repeatability coefficient (CR) was calculated as the standard deviation of those 4 measurements of each position multiplied by 2.77, so we have 4 CR for each subject. We report all values or the maximum and minimum value as preferred.
The standard error of measurement (SEM) was calculated as squared(MSe) with all the data from all the subjects, and we report only one reliability value.
If we contextualize it with numbers, we have a CR in ranges from 0.036 to 0.003. And an SEM of 0.004.
How could we conclude? Is it possible to have a procedure that is not very repeatable in individual measurements, but is nevertheless replicable in different conditions as indicated by the reliability (SEM) in this case?

Maybe you could elaborate on what you are doing? I worked with Bland and heard him talk about both those things quite often, but I never heard him mention combining them (which doesn't mean it can't be done, of course).

Yes of course. The experiment is as follows: 10 subjects are measured 4 times consecutively under the same conditions. This is repeated 4 times in 5 different positions.
The repeatability coefficient (CR) would be calculated as the standard deviation of those 4 measurements of each position multiplied by 2.77, so we have 4 CR for each subject. We report all values or the maximum and minimum value as preferred.
The standard error of measurement (SEM) would be calculated with all the data from all the subjects, and we would obtain only one reliability value.

" standard error of measurement (SEM) would be calculated " to be 100% clear, can you say how this was done?
It's also easier if you edit the question, which allows formatting, etc (and other people might not read all the comments.)

Done. SEM was calculated as SD of squared(1-ICC).

There's more than one way to calculate an ICC.

I´m calculating with R package with Jamovi. Seems that SEM calculation is = squared(MSe)

If we contextualize it with numbers, we have a CR in ranges from 0.036 to 0.003. And an SEM of 0.004.
How could we conclude? Is it possible to have a procedure that is not very repeatable in individual measurements, but is nevertheless replicable in different conditions as indicated by the reliability (SEM) in this case?
